# I want to create a 24 hour rewarding lock in my game(unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a 24 hour rewarding lock in my game(unity3d)
I want to reward a user for 24 hour after 24 hour the game object will be locked for another 24 hours how would i do it in unity ???

Comment: Depending on whether the game is an online or offline game.

If it is an offline game, one way would be to start a timer, then when the game is closed, store information about the timer (d,h,m,s) into a file so that when the game is open again, you read the timer data and keep ticking where it left.

The other option, if it is an online game, is to use a server to keep track of the timer, this way the timer will keep update in the server, even if the game is not running in the clients.

I would need more information about what you are trying to do, in order to give more information.

Comment: its offline game ...when playerwatches a video the dog will be unlocked for 24 hour and locked after 24hour.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the player 'uses' the object for the first time, you can save the object and the current time:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString('<objectnametimer>', DateTime.Now.AddHours(25).ToString());
```

This will save the new datetime, so everytime the game boots up, you can check things like this:

```
void Start() {
    var unlockDate = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString('<objectnametimer>'));
    if(unlockDate < DateTime.Now) {
        //object unlocked again
    }
    else {
        //object still locked, how long you ask?: 
        TimeSpan diff = unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        Debug.Log("object locked for " + diff.Minutes + " more minutes");
    }
}
```

I didn't check for compile errors, (I'm on my phone) But this looks promising to me :)

PS: If you want to create a countdown, just keep iterating the else code and convert it to a nice format using diff like described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT: when iterating, use [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)` for a calculatiosn every 1 second. also make sure to check each time `if (unlockedDate < DateTime.Now)` to trigger unlocking :)

Happy coding